# Comment snippets package of sublime text is not working in css

Tags: html, css

I installed sublime text and included comment snippets (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Comment-Snippets) it's working in html and others languages but it doesn't work in css whenever i wrote my comments like this:

comm-section

it gives me this output:

```
comm-section: ;
```

in html

```
/*=============================================
=            Section comment block            =
=============================================*/



/*-----  End of Section comment block  ------*/
```

how to be fixed in css like in html

Thanks for replying

Comment: This work on my TS3. In html files you have hints but in the css/less files dosnt have but it still work great. Put comm-section on your css files and press tabs.

Comment: neither tab nor ctrl+e is working..

Comment: anyone else to help ?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before, the main reason why this isn't working is because you have "EMMET" package installed and it's overriding it.

If you find yourself not really using EMMET's shortcut for css, you can disable it in EMMET's settings.

Go into Sublime: SublimeText -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet -> Settings User

Open it and type in:

```
{
"disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "source.css"
}
```

Save it, then try your comments again. It should work now.